# Азбука Морзе. Питон

Tags: python, словари, dict

Всем доброго дня!
Есть задача по азбуке Морзе на Питоне. Сделать надо через словарь.

Из условия:
Весь текст записан в единственной строке. Текст состоит из английских букв и пробелов, других символов в тексте нет. В тексте не может быть двух или более пробелов подряд. Выведите каждое слово исходного текста, закодированное азбукой Морзе, **на отдельной строке**. Количество строк в ответе должно совпадать с количеством слов в исходном тексте. Между закодированными буквами нужно ставить ровно один пробел. Например, слово «Help» превратится в «.... . .-.. .--.». Обратите внимание, что строчные и заглавные буквы кодируются одинаково.

Сам вопрос перевода решил легко - на другом курсе уже решил похожую задачу.
Но тут бьюсь над переносом (каждое слово на отдельной строке).

```
morze = {'a': '•—', 'b': '—•••', 'c': '—•—•', 'd': '—••',   
         'e': '•', 'f': '••—•', 'g': '——•', 'h': '••••',
         'i': '••', 'j': '•———', 'k': '—•—', 'l': '•—••',
         'm': '——', 'n': '—•', 'o': '———', 'p': '•——•',
         'q': '——•—', 'r': '•—•', 's': '•••', 't': '—',
         'u': '••—', 'v': '•••—', 'w': '•——', 'x': '—••—',
         'y': '—•——', 'z': '——••'}                # собственно, словарь перевода текста в код

text = input().lower().split()    # Houston we have a problem
text = '\n'.join(text)
print(text)                       # проверочный принт - каждое слово на отдельной строке                 

for i in text:
    for key, value in morze.items():
        if i==key:
            print(value, end=' ')   # однако в итоге получаем код одной строчкой
```

Есть еще вариант с костылем - я добавил в словарь еще одну пару значений для пробела: ' ': '\n'

```
morze = {'a': '•—', 'b': '—•••', 'c': '—•—•', 'd': '—••',
         'e': '•', 'f': '••—•', 'g': '——•', 'h': '••••',
         'i': '••', 'j': '•———', 'k': '—•—', 'l': '•—••',
         'm': '——', 'n': '—•', 'o': '———', 'p': '•——•',
         'q': '——•—', 'r': '•—•', 's': '•••', 't': '—',
         'u': '••—', 'v': '•••—', 'w': '•——', 'x': '—••—',
         'y': '—•——', 'z': '——••', ' ': '\n'}

text = input().lower()

for i in text:
    for key, value in morze.items():
        if i==key:
            print(value, end=' ')
```

И код Морзе переносится, однако:

- перед каждым кодом выводится **лишний пробел** (как я понимаю, унаследованный от предыдущего слова)
- в комментах пишут что с таким костылем не принимается задача, т.к. сам словарь предоставлен платформой "как есть" без права его как-то модифицировать.

Пробовал такой акт отчаяния:

```
if i==' ':
    print('\n')
```

Но там слова выводились с какими-то гигантскими промежутками...

Как реализовать перевод строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(*[' '.join(map(morze.get, word)) for word in text], sep='\n')
```

или так:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(morze.get, word)) for word in text))
```

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра с утра смогу проверить.

Comment: Я еще не освоил однострочники, пока рад когда решаю "по-сложному"))

Answer (score 1):

Думаю комментарии излишни, всё довольно ясно. Если нет - спрашивайте :)

```
morze = {'a': '•—', 'b': '—•••', 'c': '—•—•', 'd': '—••',
         'e': '•', 'f': '••—•', 'g': '——•', 'h': '••••',
         'i': '••', 'j': '•———', 'k': '—•—', 'l': '•—••',
         'm': '——', 'n': '—•', 'o': '———', 'p': '•——•',
         'q': '——•—', 'r': '•—•', 's': '•••', 't': '—',
         'u': '••—', 'v': '•••—', 'w': '•——', 'x': '—••—',
         'y': '—•——', 'z': '——••'}  

text = input().lower().split()  


for word in text:
    translated_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        translated_word += f"{morze.get(letter)} "
    print(translated_word)
```

Comment: зачем так сложно? `translated_word = ' '.join(morze.get(letter) for letter in word)`, что кстати не дает в конце ненужного пробела, а можно и так: `translated_word = ' '.join(map(morze.get, word))`

Comment: Можно и вообще полным однострочником print('\n'.join(' '.join(morze[word] for word in input().lower().split())), проблема в том что человек явно новичок в изучении python, а насколько я понимаю цель площадки в первую очередь помогать людям разобраться в их коде и ошибках возникающих там, а не решать задачи за них максимально красивым способом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разбить текст по словам, потом каждое слово по буквам, после обработки каждого слова выводить пустую строку. Код говорит сам за себя

```py
morze = {'a': '•—', 'b': '—•••', 'c': '—•—•', 'd': '—••',   
         'e': '•', 'f': '••—•', 'g': '——•', 'h': '••••',
         'i': '••', 'j': '•———', 'k': '—•—', 'l': '•—••',
         'm': '——', 'n': '—•', 'o': '———', 'p': '•——•',
         'q': '——•—', 'r': '•—•', 's': '•••', 't': '—',
         'u': '••—', 'v': '•••—', 'w': '•——', 'x': '—••—',
         'y': '—•——', 'z': '——••'}

text = input().lower().split() 

for word in text:
    for letter in word:
        print(morze[letter], end=' ') #у словарей есть встроенный метод получения значения по ключу
        
    print() #пустой print() печатает только перенос на новую строку
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде и второй принт пробовал, правда в другой комбинации... в общем, завтра с утра смогу проверить решение.

Answer (score 0):

Текст разбить на слова. Каждое слово (по буквам) написать азбукой морзе на отдельной строке, разделяя буквы пробелом. Все так?

```
# собственно, словарь перевода текста в код
morze = {'a': '•—', 'b': '—•••', 'c': '—•—•', 'd': '—••',   
     'e': '•', 'f': '••—•', 'g': '——•', 'h': '••••',
     'i': '••', 'j': '•———', 'k': '—•—', 'l': '•—••',
     'm': '——', 'n': '—•', 'o': '———', 'p': '•——•',
     'q': '——•—', 'r': '•—•', 's': '•••', 't': '—',
     'u': '••—', 'v': '•••—', 'w': '•——', 'x': '—••—',
     'y': '—•——', 'z': '——••'}                

text = input().lower().split()    # Houston we have a problem
print(text)                       
for word in text:
    out = ''
    for i in word:
        out += morze[i] + ' '
    print(out)
```

Выведет:

```
['houston', 'we', 'have', 'a', 'problem']
•••• ——— ••— ••• — ——— —• 
•—— • 
•••• •— •••— • 
•— 
•——• •—• ——— —••• •—•• • ——
```